# VBA Scripting.Dictionary Error (3021) when trying to receive an Item

Tags: vba, dictionary

I'm trying to use the dictionary I successfully filled before in the code and a very strange thing is happening. The key is in the dictionary but it can't give me the value. It gives an error instead. Here the code:

```
x = dict.Count
For i = 2 To lastRow

Key = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value
If dict.Exists(Key) Then

    val = dictIdPrice.Item(Key)
Else
    range("M" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 0, 0)
End If
Next i
```

"x" has a correct value and the If clause is entered but the Item method with an existing key gives me an error. I Can't figure out why...

The problem of reproducing an example is that the dictionary is filled from a Database but I will try.

```
Dim Key As Long
Dim val As Double
Dim Sql As String
Dim dictIdPrice
Dim lastRow As Integer

Sql = read_sql(IDs, dtFromSheet)
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = conODBC.Execute(Sql)
TotalColumns = rst.Fields.Count
records = rst.RecordCount
' check the query result is not empty etc
Set dictIdPrice = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do While Not rst.EOF

    Key = rst.Fields(0)
    If Not dictIdPrice.Exists(Key) Then
        dictIdPrice.Add Key, rst.Fields(1)
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
For i = 2 To lastRow

Key = Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value)

If dictIdPrice.Exists(Key) Then
    val = dictIdPrice.Item(Key)
Else
    range("M" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 0, 0)
End If
Next i
```

The Keys are of the form 291709, 289429, 289823, 290535,290683

Comment: The difference in dictIdPrice to dict is just a typo. I'm referencing the same dictionary...

Comment: Do you think you can provide a reproducible example?

Comment: The Err.Description says: "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."

Comment: this is a completely unrelated to the dictionary problem -- it's your Recordset traversal that is causing this. Look up how to iterate recordset properly and what to check for - hint: `rst.EOF` and `MoveFirst()`

Comment: I was guessing it has something to do with the recordset however after leaving the Loop I'm done with the recordset. If (rst.EOF) Then
    rst.MoveFirst
End If - would that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is on this line:

```
dictIdPrice.Add Key, rst.Fields(1)
```

Try this instead:

```
dictIdPrice.Add Key, rst.Fields(1).Value
```

The issue is that when you store `rst.Fields(1)` in the dictionary, you are actually storing the object `rst.Fields(1)` instead of just whatever its value is.  Later, when attempting to read it back out of the dictionary, if the recordset is no longer pointing to a record, `val = dcitIdPrice.Item(Key)` evaluates the default member, which is Value, but without a current record it fails.